# Model association is off for joining users table on comments table for a submission

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model, associations, cakephp-2.0

My associations in CakePHP are a bit off. Here is the problem. I have a `users` table
and a `comments` table. When retrieving a submission I want to join the `users` table
on the `comments` table with Comment.user_id == User.id.

**Comment Model:**

```
class Comment extends AppModel {
  var $name = 'Comment';
  var $belongsTo = array('User');

  var $hasMany = array(
    'CommentsLike' => array(
      'className' => 'CommentsLike'
    ),
    'Comment' => array(
      'className' => 'Comment'
    )
  );

  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
      'className' => 'User',
      'joinTable' => 'comments',
      'foreignKey' => 'Comment.user_id',
      'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id'
    ),
    'Submission' => array(
      'className' => 'Submission'
    )
  );
```

**User Model:**

```
class User extends AppModel {
  var $name = 'User'; 
  var $hasMany = array('Comment');

  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
      'className' => 'Comment',
      'joinTable' => 'comments',
      'foreignKey' => 'Comment.user_id',
      'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
    ),  
    'Submission' => array(
      'className' => 'Submission',
      'order' => 'Submission.created DESC'
    )   
  );
```

When I grab a `submission`, it grabs all comments for it, but it doesn't join on
the `users` table which is what I want

**Submission Model:**

```
class Submission extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Submission';
    var $belongsTo = array(
      'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User'
      )   
    );  

    var $hasMany = array(
      'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'order' => 'Comment.created DESC',
        'conditions' => array(
          'Comment.deleted' => 0
        )   
      ),  
      'SubmissionsVote' => array(
        'className' => 'SubmissionsVote'
      ),  
      'SubmissionThumbnails' => array(
        'className' => 'SubmissionThumbnails'
      )   
    );
```

A find on a submission will return this:

```
[Submission] => Array
    (
        // removed for sake of stackoverflow length
    )

[User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [username] => bob_cobb
    )

[Comment] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [submission_id] => 112
                [comment] => this is a test comment
                [user_id] => 2
                [created] => 5 minutes ago
                [deleted] => 
                [parent_id] => 
            )

    )
```

As you can see `[Comment][0]` should also have `[Comment][0][User]` or something similar.

Why would I want this? Simple: I want to grab the username of the person who
commented by the foreign key of user_id from the `comments` table. I've read the docs and tutorials and pretty sure I'm close on this but not sure what's holding me back.

Here is a screenshot of the `comments` table:
[image: comments table]

Here is a screenshot of the `users` table structure:
[image: users table]

Answer (score 0):

You can a couple of options:

Either set the recursive property in the Submission model to the level you need to fetch back your associated data ( see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive )

or (more preferable) use the Containable behaviour ( see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html ) to specify what related data to return:

```
class Submission extends AppModel

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

}
```

Use it like this in your find:

```
$data = $this->Submission->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array(your conditions here),
    'contain'=>array(
        'User,
        'Comment'=>array(
            'User'
        )
    )
));
```

Most people use containable in every model so add it to AppModel and set AppModel::recursive to -1